# After running Pyinstaller, Sqlite3 update query breaks

Tags: python, sqlite, pyinstaller

The following function works fine until I compile with PyInstaller: Then I get "Error binding parameter 0. Probably unsupported type." The line showing the error is the "cur.execute" line. I've checked the Pyinstaller docs, but couldn't find anything related to this issue. I'm using Python 2.7.

UPDATE** I've narrowed it down to some kind of incompatibility between Iron Python and console python2.7. I developed the program using the Python(x,y) package, and the Spyder2 IDE. I ran the program in the Iron Python console. I also encountered the above problem when running in the normal python console and got the same error. The problem isn't a Pyinstaller it's just some kind of incompatibility between IP and Python2.7. I'm still researching so if anyone has the answer, please let me know.

```
def update_clients(self):
    #Get client id from list
    cid = None
    try:
        cid = self.client_list_id()
    except:            
        QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Warning', 'You must first select a client before you update')


    if cid:
        #Get update items
        first = self.lineEdit_c_first.text()        
        last = self.lineEdit_c_last.text()
        add1 = self.lineEdit_c_address1.text()
        add2 = self.lineEdit_c_address2.text()
        city = self.lineEdit_c_city.text()
        state = self.lineEdit_c_state.text()
        zipp = self.lineEdit_c_zip.text()        
        phone = self.lineEdit_c_phone.text()
        cell = self.lineEdit_c_phone_cell.text()
        off = self.lineEdit_c_phone_office.text()
        email = self.lineEdit_c_email.text()  
        notes = self.textEdit_c_notes.toPlainText() 
        #Update database
        conn = sqlite3.connect('gibbs.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        sql = ("""
        UPDATE clients
        SET 
        firstname = ?, 
        lastname = ?,
        address1 = ?,
        address2 = ?,
        city = ?,
        state = ?,
        zip = ?,
        phone = ?,
        officephone = ?,
        cell = ?,
        email = ?,
        notes = ?        
        WHERE rowid = ?
        """)
        cur.execute(sql, (first, last, add1, add2, city, state, zipp, phone, off, cell, email, notes, cid,))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Success', 'Database successfully updated')
```

The table was created with the code below which shows the data types.

```
def create_clients():
    try:
        conn = create_connection()
        print conn
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE clients (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        firstname TEXT,
        lastname TEXT,
        address1 TEXT,
        address2 TEXT,
        city TEXT,
        state TEXT,
        zip TEXT,
        phone TEXT,
        officephone TEXT,
        cell TEXT,
        email TEXT,
        notes TEXT    
        )     
        """)
        conn.close()
    except:
        print "table already exists"
```

Comment: First thing I would do is to add `print repr(first)`, or something similar, right before `cur.execute`.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the line `print type(first)` just before the query and running the program the output was different in the two consoles.The Iron Python console outputs: `<type 'unicode'>` and in Python2.7 console it is: `<class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QString'>`. I solved by adding the 'str' function when getting my text from the PYQT4 lineEdits. For example: `first = str(self.lineEdit_c_first.text())`.